# Gradient map as opacity in a HTML5 canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Is there a way to create an opacity map on a canvas element
I am trying to fade a generated image as shown below.

EXAMPLE:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to directly draw an image with a gradiant mask, but you could pre-draw the image to a separate canvas, and use [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) to draw a masking linear gradient, then draw that canvas using `drawImage` to the main canvas.

### Working Example:

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById('cvs');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

// Draw some background colors.
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF6666";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 200);
ctx.fillStyle = "#6666FF";
ctx.fillRect(150, 0, 150, 200);

// Load the image.
img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    // Create a canvas in memory and draw the image to it.
    var icvs = document.createElement('canvas');
    icvs.width = img.width;
    icvs.height = img.height;
    var ictx = icvs.getContext('2d');
    ictx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // For masking.
    ictx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

    // Draw the masking gradient.
    var gradient = ictx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, icvs.height);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, "transparent");
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
    ictx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ictx.fillRect(0, 0, icvs.width, icvs.height);

    // Draw the separate canvas to the main canvas.
    ctx.drawImage(icvs, 25, 25, 250, 150);
};
img.src = '//i.stack.imgur.com/dR8i9.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```